# run php echo inside a php echo?

Tags: php, css

I have a echo call outputting some HTML code, some of this code include a css, in this css i'm trying to execute some php code.

variable set before echo

```
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' );
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
```

Then in the echo:

```
    echo'
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="test.ico" rel="shortcut icon"  />
<style>
html {background:#000;
background: url("<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>") no-repeat fixed 0% 0% / cover #000;}
```

i've tried several of ways to run the php inside the echo but i fail, if i put the php inside '' tags page will not load, what am i doing wrong here or is it impossible to echo new php code inside a php echo?

Thank you!

Comment: use this  "  instid of '

Comment: Please learn basic php syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo'
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="test.ico" rel="shortcut icon"  />
<style>
html {background:#000;
background: url("'.$selectedBg.'") no-repeat fixed 0% 0% / cover #000;}';
```

Comment: Awesome this worked, i though i did try this but i must have typo'd it

Comment: @karnehe Glad to help ;). Please, check this post as a proper answer for Your question :). Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

So there is actually a misunderstanding :)

Since echo is a php instruction, you do not have to re-open and re-close php tags () but you can simply use concatenation. Example :

```
echo "Hello there ". $name ." ! How are u ?";
```

Opening and closing php tags is only usefull when you're in a HTML display such as :

```
<span>Hello <?php echo $name; ?> ! How are u ? </span>
```

This is really some basic stuff and you should really get used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo'
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="test.ico" rel="shortcut icon"  />
<style>
html {background:#000;
background: url("'.$selectedBg.'") no-repeat fixed 0% 0% / cover #000;}
```